# Validation of a textbox not working

Tags: c#, jquery, regex, asp.net-mvc, validation

I've been racking my brain but can't see what's wrong with this. Validation is working fine throughout the site, but it doesn't fire for this input. I'm using .NET 4, MVC 4, EF 5, jQuery 1.8. Any ideas?

**Schedule.cs**

```
{
    [MetadataType(typeof(ScheduleMetaData))]
    public partial class Schedule
    {

    }

    public class ScheduleMetaData
    {
        [RegularExpression(@"^#(([0-9a-fA-F]{2}){3}|([0-9a-fA-F]){3})$", ErrorMessage = "Invalid hex color")]
        [Required]
        public string Color { get; set; }
    } 
}
```

**Schedule.cs (built by EF)**

```
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class Schedule
    {
        public Schedule()
        {
            this.OriginDependency = new HashSet<Dependency>();
            this.EndpointDependency = new HashSet<Dependency>();
        }

        public int ScheduleId { get; set; }
        public string ScheduleName { get; set; }
        public string Color { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Dependency> OriginDependency { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Dependency> EndpointDependency { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Edit.cshtml**

```
<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Color)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Color)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Color)
</div>
```

**BundleConfig.cs** (snippet)

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
        "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*",
        "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive*"));
```

Comment: What are those brackets around your Schedule.cs code?

Comment: What is "this input" ?

Comment: The braces around my Schedule.cs code are the project namespace. My input control is generated by @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Color) ... it's a text box.

Comment: Consider checking the output HTML/JavaScript to ensure the generated Regular Expression looks correct as well as the if statements surrounding it.

Comment: Also your regular expression would be slightly more readable like this `^#(?:[A-Fa-f0-9]{6}|[A-Fa-f0-9]{3})$`
And have you tried another regular expression that you have proven works elsewhere?

Comment: If I replace it with an alternative validation, such as string length rather than a regex, it also fails to fire. I'll check the generated javascript, thanks...

Comment: Are both `Schedule` classes definitely in the same namespace?

Comment: Please show full Edit.cshtml

Comment: Which browser are you testing with? Do you have ClientValidationEnabled, and do both client and server side validation fail to fire? Can you post the code of the action method that receives the post, please.

Comment: @Floradu88 apologies, was away for a couple of days. As Rowan and hajirazin explained, it was indeed mismatching namespaces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your namespace of both the partial classes are required to be same. If not, .NET will take it as two different classes and metadata will not work on that. As mentioned by  @Rowan Freeman in comment, please make sure that namespace for both the classes are same.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you have different namespaces due to the folder they are located into, or maybe there are different assemblies that hold the two classes.

Also due to lack of details from Edit.Cshtml there might be a missing include:
`Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")` in that View/PartialView(Check browser console for errors).

Make sure that both classes have the same namespace:

```
namespace ExampleNamespace
{
    [MetadataType(typeof(ScheduleMetaData))]
    public partial class Schedule
    {

    }

    public class ScheduleMetaData
    {
        [RegularExpression(@"^#(([0-9a-fA-F]{2}){3}|([0-9a-fA-F]){3})$", ErrorMessage = "Invalid hex color")]
        [Required]
        public string Color { get; set; }
    } 
}
```

Where ExampleNamespace should be taken from here:
EF generated class.
    namespace ExampleNamespace 
    {
        using System;
        using System.Collections.Generic;

```
    public partial class Schedule
    {
        public Schedule()
        {
            this.OriginDependency = new HashSet<Dependency>();
            this.EndpointDependency = new HashSet<Dependency>();
        }

        public int ScheduleId { get; set; }
        public string ScheduleName { get; set; }
        public string Color { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Dependency> OriginDependency { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Dependency> EndpointDependency { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: [off topic] Why did you approve [the edit mentioned here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/211655/180276)? It should have been rejected

Comment: I must have been a slip from my side, I think i clicked edit by mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Where is your script bundle included? If you include the bundle too late the validation won't work because it can't find the `jquery.validate` library. Please check where your bundle include is done.

You can also use Firebug in Firefox (or Chrome's Developer Tools), go to the Net tab and check that jquery.validate is correctly loaded. While you're in there, check for any other javascript errors (on the console tab).